# GcmIntentService send message to running activity

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, intentservice

I have an android application where I need to notificate the user WHILE he's running a specific activity, that something happened.

Notifications won't do the job for me, since I need to inform the user via a Dialog, send data to the server and launch another activity... I mean, I know that when this message is delivered, the user will be using the application and seeing the screen belonging to the acrivity I want to send the message to.

That message should be triggered by the GCM service.
I've done everything to receive the message and I currently have my GcmIntentService working fine (following [this](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html) link).

Now, I tried to send a Message to the activity, by defining a Handler in it like this:

```
public Handler _handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
```

I have 2 issues here:

1) I don't really know if this Handler is going to be triggered on the actual running activity

2) On this "handleMessage" event I don't have the running activity's context, so I can't, for instance, rise an AlertDialog (I get NullPointerException)

How can I achieve this? Should I have to re-think the communication between the service and the activity?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to notify user in android with : [This](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html)

check Code :

```
public void sendNotification(String msg) {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            new Intent(context, returnClass), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
            .setContentTitle(
                    context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

For your question 2-

> On this "handleMessage" event I don't have the running activity's context, so I can't, for instance, rise an AlertDialog (I get NullPointerException)

You can use this as Refrence to context (GcmService.this )

Hope that help

Comment: 1) Notifications won't do the job for me, since I need to inform the user via a Dialog, send data to the server and launch another activity... I mean, I know that when this message is delivered, the user will be using the application and seeing the screen belonging to the acrivity I want to send the message to 2) The handle of the message is in my activity, not in my service, and "this" is not working either